# Can a program call fflush() on the same FILE* concurrently?

Tags: c, multithreading, file, stdio, fflush

Can anything bad happen (like undefined behavior, file corruption, etc.) if several threads concurrently call `fflush()` on the same `FILE*` variable?

Clarification: I don't mean writing the file concurrently. I only mean flushing it concurrently.

The threads do not read or write the file concurrently (they only write the file inside a critical section, one thread at a time). They only flush outside of the critical section, to release the critical section sooner so to let the others do the other work (except file writing).

Though it may happen that one thread is writing the file (inside the critical section), while another thread(s) is flushing the file (outside the critical section).

Comment: This sounds as though you are asking it from a design perspective, rather than trying to eliminate an explanation for a bug — perhaps it would be worth making that more explicit.

Comment: Given the answer that `FILE`s are thread-safe, one negative consequence could be that one thread is forced to wait for another to flush, though that would probably only matter if you require fairly high performance. Using functions like `flockfile` ¿or `flock`? could _conceivably_ lead to deadlock, but probably not in the case you describe.

Comment: @PJTraill , that's all right: if one thread is flushing, and another thread writes something and then figures out it need to flush too, then all it can do is to wait for the first thread to return what's at `FILE*` into a consistent state (flushing everything it has written, and maybe even what the second thread has written - this depends on the race), and then the second thread should ensure that what it has just written gets flushed too. Of course there is a better approach with asynchronous flushing in a dedicated thread, but that's more complex thus out of the scope.

Comment: You seem to assume that flushing only delays other threads also trying to flush, but my understanding of the quotes in 2501’s answer is that, since there is a _single_ lock per stream, it also delays threads trying to write — and that could be undesirable!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Streams in C<sup>1</sup> are thread-safe<sup>2</sup>. Functions are required to lock the stream before accessing it<sup>3</sup>.

The fflush function is thread-safe and may be called from any thread at any time, as long as the stream is an output stream or an update stream<sup>4</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> As per the current standard, which is C11.

<sup>2</sup> (Quoted from: ISO/IEC 9899:201x 7.21.3 Streams 7)
Each stream has an associated lock that is used to prevent data races when multiple
threads of execution access a stream, and to restrict the interleaving of stream operations
performed by multiple threads. Only one thread may hold this lock at a time. The lock is
reentrant: a single thread may hold the lock multiple times at a given time.

<sup>3</sup> (Quoted from: ISO/IEC 9899:201x 7.21.3 Streams 8)
All functions that read, write, position, or query the position of a stream lock the stream
before accessing it. They release the lock associated with the stream when the access is
complete.
reentrant: a single thread may hold the lock multiple times at a given time.

<sup>4</sup> (Quoted from: ISO/IEC 9899:201x 7.21.5.2 The fflush function 2)
If stream points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent
operation was not input, the fflush function causes any unwritten data for that stream
to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; otherwise, the behavior is
undefined.

Comment: Does MSVC compiler follow these on x86/x86_64 Windows?

Comment: @SergeRogatch If it is C11 compliant, then yes.

Comment: @SergeRogatch Aparently it is safe: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz.aspx

Comment: @cat VS is not even C99 compliant.

Comment: @2501 Eheheh, well, what hope is there for the universe? Maybe they should just encourage their users to use Clang instead.

Comment: @2501, yes, great, for both 2013 and 2015 they say "This function locks the calling thread and is therefore thread-safe. For a non-locking version, see _fflush_nolock." on that MSDN page.

Comment: _"The lock is"_ What?

Comment: @black a faulty copy-paste. Thanks.

Comment: C streams were not always safe. I recall having to track down a bug where they were not. Nevertheless, if you hit such a bug today, bug your compiler vendor.

Comment: @cat Microsoft Visual C++ aims to be a C++ compiler, not a C compiler. AFAIK they do support C++14 in recent versions.

Comment: I welcome useful corrections, but please stop editing my answer to change its look.

Comment: We use `fwrite` and `fflush` with the same `FILE` concurrently in code compiled with MSVC 2015 without any problems. The writes are being neatly interleaved in the output file.

Answer (score 12):

The POSIX.1 and C-language functions that operate on character streams (represented by pointers to objects of type FILE) are *required* by POSIX.1c to be implemented in such a way that reentrancy is achieved (see ISO/IEC 9945:1-1996, §8.2).

This requirement has a drawback; it imposes substantial performance penalties because of the synchronization that must be built into the implementations of the functions for the sake of reentrancy. POSIX.1c addresses this tradeoff between reentrancy (safety) and performance by introducing high-performance, but non-reentrant (potentially unsafe), versions of the following C-language standard I/O functions: getc(), getchar(), putc() and putchar(). The non-reentrant versions are named getc_unlocked(), and so on, to stress their unsafeness.

Note however as others have noted: Many popular systems (including Windows and Android) are not POSIX compliant.

Comment: ▲ For “_not POSIX compliant_”, but do you mean that `fflush` is not thread safe, that they do not implement POSIX.1c or that they do not claim compliance? A list (or link to one) of platforms (with version information) and their compliance _in this respect_ might be a useful resource.

Comment: I don't know if Google promises that `fflush` will be thread-safe,  [even if it currently is](https://sourceforge.net/u/lluct/me722-cm/ci/86c46fc79a15bc9500fbb47241a15c148b8abb01/tree/bionic/libc/stdio/fflush.c), but Microsoft [does](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz.aspx) at least on Windows.

Answer (score 9):

You are not supposed to call `fflush()` on an input stream, it invokes undefined behavior, so I shall assume the stream is open in write or update mode.

If the stream is open in update mode (`"w+"` or `"r+"`), the last operation must not be a read when you call `fflush()`.  Since the stream is used in various threads asynchronously, it would be difficult to ensure this without some form of interprocess communication and synchronization or locking if you do any reads. There is still a valid reason to open the file in update mode, but make sure you do not do any reads after you start the `fflush` thread.

`fflush()` does not modify the current position. It merely causes any buffered output to be written to the system.  The streams are usually protected by a lock, so calling `fflush()` in one thread should not mess the output performed by another thread, but it may change the timing of the system writes. If multiple threads output the the same `FILE*`, the order in which the interleaving occurs is indeterminate anyway.  Furthermore, if you use `fseek()` is different threads for the same stream, you **must** use a lock of your own to ensure consistency between the `fseek()` and the following output.

Although it seems OK to do it, it is probably not recommended. You could instead call `fflush()` after the write operations in each thread, before releasing the lock.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple answer, you may not do that, as the file has a single "current position". How do you keep track of it? Is the file opened for sequential access or random? In the latter case you could open it multiple times (one for each thread), and yet devise ways to keep the file structure consistent.

Comment: Ok, I should add this to the question: the threads do not read or write the file concurrently (they only write the file inside a critical section, one thread at a time). They only flush outside of the critical section, to release the critical section sooner so to let the others do the other work (except file writing).

Comment: `fflush()` does not modify the current position.

Comment: It could be easier then, I would consider a different way, create another worker thread (no windows, timers, message-queues etc) which will only be performing the flushing (or maybe the writing as well?). The thread proc would only contain a loop with a SleepEx() command. The other threads would be sending APC requests for writng, and the APC proc would execute them (one at a time, as they are queued). Implementation is only a few source lines, and you don't really need to read much, if you don't know how to do it already. See the documentation for QueueUserAPC() function.

Answer (score 0):

The actual answer seems to be that streams are (meant to be) thread-safe themselves, but, if that weren't the case, your issue could be the `fflush` occurs (outside a lock) while another thread *is* writing (inside a critical section).

As such, I'd work with the model of the virtual machine you're coding against and put the `fflush()` inside a critical section too.